# Is an open subset of a compact surface with connected boundary completely determined by its fundamental group?

Tags: general-topology, surfaces, fundamental-groups

> Is an open, connected subset of a compact surface with connected boundary  determined (up to homeomorphism) by its fundamental group?

If we weaken the hypotheses, I can see how this can fail:

- A cylinder and circle are both subsets of the torus with $F_1$ as their fundamental group, so the requirement that the subset be open is necessary.
- A torus with a point removed and a twice-puntured disk both have $F_2$ as their fundamental group, so the result can fail if we allow subsets with disconnected boundaries.
- Since a disconnected spaces does not generally have a single uniquely defined fundamental group (we have to specify where the base point lies), requiring connectedness seems reasonable.

It seems like open subsets of a compact surface with a connected boundary are sufficiently 'nice' that this result could hold.

This question came to me when I was [answering this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381206/complete-toroidal-graphs/1381298#1381298): if it were true, then we could enumerate the possible faces of a graph embedding in any surface $S$ by simply enumerating the subgroups of $S \setminus \{p\}$.

Comment: Isn't a cylinder homeomorphic to  a punctured disc?

Comment: @posilon Indeed it is.  I believe my new example should work (since the $1$ point compactification of $T_2 \setminus \{p\}$ is a torus, and the $1$ point compactification of $D_2 \setminus\{p_1, p_1\}$ is not a surface).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I interpret your question as "if $X$ is an open subset of a closed surface, and has only one [end](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_(topology)), is it determined by its fundamental group?"

Yes. In fact, a surface $\Sigma$ with one end and fundamental group $F_{2g}$ is homeomorphic to the punctured genus $g$ surface, and this is the only possible fundamental group. To prove this use the observation of [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/4175/40804) and exploit the fact that, because $\Sigma$ is an open subspace of a closed surface, it cannot have infinite genus.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (I'll have to think more about it when I get the chance).  However, I was looking at the boundary of the open subset as a subset of the larger surface (so, for example, a cylinder could have as its boundary in the torus a single circle).

Comment: @Strants: Do you demand the "boundary" be a manifold? If so, the above answer applies but with one or possible two ends, and it's again determined by the fundamental group. If not, there's no hope of what you want being true.

Comment: (I am interpreting "boundary" here to mean "$\overline{X} \setminus X$".)

Comment: That was the notion of boundary I was intending, yes.  I would be fine with requiring that the boundary be a manifold.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Strants: For a counterexample in the non-manifold case, you can embed the twice-punctured disc into the genus 2 surface such that its boundary is homeomorphic to a circle with an arc through the center. You can embed the punctured torus into this same manifold.